# Sign Gnosis Safe transaction with JS

Tags: javascript, gnosis-safe, gnosis

My code:

```
const owners = [{
    address: "0x1Ebda288BB081747680e356bc6f1A0b29B39Ae3d",
    privateKey: ""
}]
let sender = owners[0].address
let senderPrivateKey = owners[0].privateKey
let SAFE_ADDRESS = "0x7B7DADc784d3ddB36F3fBF0900e9C933A1fFa0Cc"
let CHAIN_ID = 137

//SAFE TRANSACTION DATA
let tx = {
    to: '0x7B7DADc784d3ddB36F3fBF0900e9C933A1fFa0Cc', //contract to call
    value: 0, //native token value in wei
    data: '0x0', //data to call contract with
    operation: 0, // 0 = CALL, 1 = DELEGATECALL, 2 = CREATE
    safeTxGas: 0, //gas limit for calls to other contracts
    baseGas: 0, //gas used for safeTx (signature checks...) excluding calls to other contracts
    gasPrice: 0, // gas price used for the refund calculation
    gasToken: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", //native token (ETH/BNB...)
    refundReceiver: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", //address to receive gas refunds, if 0x0, tx.origin (original caller) will be used
    signatures: "0x"
}

let nonce = await safeWeb3Instance.methods.nonce().call() //can be also stored off-chain, if there are multiple pending txs not yet executed
let msg = await safeWeb3Instance.methods.encodeTransactionData(tx.to, tx.value, tx.data, tx.operation, tx.safeTxGas, tx.baseGas, tx.gasPrice, tx.gasToken, tx.refundReceiver, nonce).call()

//SIGN SAFE TRANSACTION
for (i in owners){
    let signature = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msg, owners[i].privateKey)
    signature.signature = signature.signature.replace(signature.v.substring(2), (parseInt(signature.v.substring(2), 16) + 4).toString(16)) //add 4 to v

    tx.signatures += signature.signature.substring(2); //substring to remove 0x
}

let params = Object.values(tx)
let data = safeEthersInterface.encodeFunctionData("execTransaction", params) 

//ON-CHAIN TRANSACTION
let rawTransaction = {
    "from": sender,
    "nonce": "0x" + nonce.toString(16),
    "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice * 1e9),
    "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
    "to": SAFE_ADDRESS,
    "data": data,
    "chainId": CHAIN_ID
};
let createTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, senderPrivateKey)
let receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(createTransaction.rawTransaction);
```

It's failing with GS026 error (Invalid owner provided), but the address used to sign data is the valid owner. (e.g. https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7a9e9edc5ba5b625de45a50b94c8d21d8d57ad57c6180eb0881503eb0f315597)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add the signatures and public keys of the owners?

Comment: @mikheevm added address and private key for test owner.

Comment: please remove the private key!! and never share it with anyone. we need a public key

Comment: we need the public key (aka address) and the signature returned by `web3.eth.accounts.sign`

Comment: just fyi the private key is still seen through the edit history, you may want to delete the question and ask again

Answer (score 1):

Currently you use `encodeTransactionData` to get the message that you are signing with `web3.eth.accounts.sign`. The correct method to use is [`getTransactionHash`](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L396-L422).

For the contracts the transaction data has to be hashed before it is signed. The `sign` method first appends the Ethereum message prefix (see https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) before it hashes, therefore you get a wrong result.

Keep in mind that if you use multiple owners, that their signatures need to be sorted by their addresses (more info here: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/signatures)